# Data Tables jQuery plugin

Tags: jquery-plugins, pagination, datatables

I am using jQuery data table plugin to sort, filter and paginate as in the below link. It's working perfectly fine. No issues with that. The pagination is displayed in the bottom right corner of the table. I want it to be displayed at the top of the table, beside the search box. I tried altering the css but didn't succeed.

Is it possible to change? Below is the link which i refered. Please help..

http://datatables.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do that and much more using DOM customization as shown in [this example](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/basic_init/dom.html)

Basically you must use the sDom parameter

When customising DataTables for your own usage, you might find that the default position of the feature elements (filter input etc) is not quite to your liking. To address this issue DataTables takes inspiration from the CSS 3 Advanced Layout Module and provides the sDom initialisation parameter which can be set to indicate where you which particular features to appear in the DOM. You can also specify div wrapping containers (with classes) to provide complete layout flexibility. The syntax available is:

l - Length changing
f - Filtering input
t - The table!
i - Information
p - Pagination
r - pRocessing
< and > - div elements
<"class" and > - div with a class
Examples: <"wrapper"flipt>, ip>

So for example you can use

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#example').dataTable({
    "sDom" : 'lpfrti'
  });
});
```

http://live.datatables.net/awemoc/edit#javascript,html,live

Comment: Thanks a ton Nicola... With a little bit of CSS changes, it is now displaying as i wanted... Wouldn't have been able to figure this out without your help...